# IBM MQ Binding Element for Non Soap/JMS Messages

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ibm-mq

I'm trying to read messages of an MQ, I've been following [this approach from IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un12064_.htm)
 to create "a WCF custom channel by suppling binding and endpoint information programmatically".

I've got a similar mechanism working with SOAP message which have a header specifying the class and method to be called for each incoming message.

I'm now wanting to process messages which are not in SOAP format from another queue, but I get this error;

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: WCFCH0314E: The recieved message 'ID: ...' could not be de-serialized The message format or contents is not consitent with the selected message encoder and cannot be interpreted as a SOAP/JMS message. Review the linked exceptions for futher details. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Unrecognized message version.

This makes sense as the example uses SoapJmsIbmTransportBindingElement. Unfotunately, there doesn't seem to be any alternative binding element in IBM.XMS.WCF.

Is it possible to create a WCF custom channel for MQ for non-soap messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently MQ WCF custom channel supports only SOAP messages, no support for non-SOAP messages. The MQ WCF custom channel looks for specific message headers to identify the incoming message as a WCF message. The WCFCH0314E exception will be thrown if those headers are not present.